# copy wp-postmeta from post to another in wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to make my site bilingual, so I need to duplicate posts and copies the postmeta from post to another. For this reason, i logged all query inserted to postmeta using trigger, and i try to execute it using this stored procedure but i have this error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(s,concat(',',_ID,','),concat(',',_NEWID,',')) PREPARE stmt1 FROM s; EXECU' at line 16

```
DELIMITER \\

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_postmeta_dynamic_sql`\\
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_postmeta_dynamic_sql` (_ID int, _NEWID int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE s varchar(1024);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT fwd_sql FROM logtable
                     WHERE fwd_sql LIKE CONCAT('%,',_ID,',%')
                     and modtable LIKE 'wp_postmeta';
                     
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN cur1;
        read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO s;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        REPLACE(s,concat(',',_ID,','),concat(',',_NEWID,','))
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM s;
        EXECUTE stmt1 ;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
        END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;


END\\

DELIMITER ;
```

can you help me in this problem, Is there another way to resolve this issue?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any plugin like WPML for translation before trying to progress with this idea ?

Comment: yes, but WPML has many errors with arabian language, now i'm using Polylang plugin but i need to avoid insert post more than once, i want to make it automatically

Comment: You can edit that and make your own .po and .mo file to get your job done.

Comment: i need to duplicate post in my case for more statistics and many other reasons...

Comment: then you can try retrieve and update post meta data for all products.

Comment: can you resolve my code error?